# Discord user name with many spaces + command with more args

Tags: python, discord.py

What im trying to do is this particular command to work, but when i try to mute members with spaces in their names like for example `t!mute sweaty dolphin dude 1 reason...` it just doesnt work

```
@client.command()
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
@commands.has_role('Staff')
async def mute(ctx,member:discord.Member,mute_time:int, *,reason:str):
     #My code....
```

I've also tried

```
@client.command()
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
@commands.has_role('Staff')
async def mute(ctx, mute_time:int, reason:str, *, member:discord.Member):
     #My code....
```

And it works well, but what i really need is the member name to go fisrt, then the time and the reason at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`discord.Message` has a property called `mentions`, which is a list of mentioned members in a given message.

So what you can do is remove the parts pertaining to the member from the paramaters of the function, i.e. make it `async def mute(ctx, mute_time: int, *, reason: str)` and, in the function's code, declare `muted_user = ctx.message.mentions[0]`. This will work as long as you make sure to mention the user when using the mute command. You could even extend this to mute multiple people at once (i.e. all the mentions given in the message).

Comment: The converter should be able to handle mentions.  `t!mute @sweaty dolphin dude 1 reason` should work just fine with the signature in the question.

Comment: Ah, true actually, so no need to remove that from the parameters, just make sure the user is always mentioned. Should I edit my solution to reflect that, or leave as it is? I'm not sure what is the proper etiquette =p

Answer (score 1):

When writing a member's name that has spaces in it, plop quotation marks around it, like so:

`t!mute "sweaty dolphin dude" 1 reason`

The same goes for any arguments that you might want to have spaces in.